# How measure the space to a TextView rendered in Activity from topbar using Android XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to is there any way to get the space from the top of this TextView.

```
val location = IntArray(2)
textView.getLocationOnScreen(location)
return Point(location[0],location[1])
```

I tried to get location of using this method. but not getting the value of the space.
Is there any clue.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: have you tried `textview.Y` and `textview.X` or `textview.top`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total height of the screen in real pixels by using `resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels` and any view's real height, width, x and y coordinates by accessing their respective properties. You can calculate the space as a substraction of coordinates or as a sum of your view's heights. Anyway any measurement operations must be done after the activity is drawn otherwise the properties are invalid. As such you can use a *tree observer*

```
treeObserver = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        //your measurments and updates go here eg.
        val space = view1.y -view2.y
}
viewToWorkWith.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(treeObserver)
```

Do not forget to dispose of the observer

```
onDestroy(){
 treeObserver ?: viewToWorkWith.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        treeObserver
    )
}
```

Edit: This observer is called constantly and is running on UI thread, so instead on removing it on `onDestroy()` callback is better to remove it in listener's lambda once you are done measuring everything.

```
treeObserver = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        //your measurments and updates go here eg.
        val space = view1.y -view2.y
        //...
        viewToWorkWith.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        treeObserver
    )
}
```